# How do I get ruby to honor a local hosts file?

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, hosts

I have an rspec testsuite that I use to test our internal and public facing API. Usually all I have to do to test the service is setup my parameters (e.g test urls) and from there the tests connect to the required service and do their thing.

My question is, how to I get ruby to honor my host file entries? In this specific scenario I'm trying to hit our pre-live servers, which use the same urls as our live environment, but obviously are on an entirely different IP cluster.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you are doing some very low-level stuff, Ruby will *not* perform DNS name resolution by itself, it will simply call the appropriate OS API. So, you need to figure out how to configure your operating system to use a local hosts file.

Comment: Is the fact that the web browsers on the same machine resolve to the correct IP an indication that the machine is configured correctly? Or is there a lower level that needs to be configured?